# Can't read directly from URL using AsynTask

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to develop an application that reads jokes from a URL. I am using an AsyncTask to read from URL and then put the string to a textView. But I can't figure out why it isn't working.
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button oneJokeBtn, threeJokesBtn;
private final static String ERROR_TAG = "Download Error";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Capturing our buttons from the view
    oneJokeBtn = findViewById(R.id.joke_1);
    threeJokesBtn = findViewById(R.id.joke_3);
    // Register the onClick listener
    oneJokeBtn.setOnClickListener(buttonHandler);
    threeJokesBtn.setOnClickListener(buttonHandler);
    // Declaring the Spinner
    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.length_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Spinner onItemSelector implemented in the OnCreate Method
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), R.string.short_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), R.string.medium_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), R.string.long_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
/** AsyncTask that reads one joke directly from the URL and adds it to the textView */
private class Download1JokeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String mResponse = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.progress_msg));
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String joke = null;
        try {
            // Open a connection to the web service
            URL url = new URL( "http://www-staff.it.uts.edu.au/~rheise/sarcastic.cgi" );
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            // Obtain the input stream
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            // The joke is a one liner, so just read one line.
            joke = in.readLine();
            // Close the connection
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(ERROR_TAG, "Exception: ", e);
            mResponse = getString(R.string.fail_msg);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(ERROR_TAG, "Exception: ", e);
            mResponse = getString(R.string.fail_msg);
        }
        return joke;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String joke) {
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.tv_joke);
        if (joke == null) {
            tv.setText(R.string.fail_msg);
        }
        else {
            tv.setText(joke);
        }
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}

/** AsyncTask that reads three jokes directly from the URL and adds it to the textView */
private class Download3JokeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String[]> {
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.three_jokes_btn));
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        int count = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                // Obtain the input stream
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                // The joke is a one liner, so just read one line.
                String joke;
                while ((joke = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(joke);
                }
                // Close the connection
                in.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(ERROR_TAG, "Exception: ", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(ERROR_TAG, "Exception: ", e);
            }
            publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        setProgress(0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
        super.onPostExecute(strings);
    }
}
/** onClickListener that gets the id of the button pressed and download jokes accordingly */
OnClickListener buttonHandler = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.joke_1:
                new Download1JokeAsyncTask().execute();
                break;
            case R.id.joke_3:
                new Download3JokeAsyncTask().execute();
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

The AsyncTask is called Download1JokeAsyncTask, it is supposed to read from URL and then put it into a text view. and I've put an error message to appear in the text view if the joke (the string where the joke is stored) is null.
And always the text view says that it failed to download a message.
Please help.

Comment: if you try to open the URL on your code (`http://www-staff.it.uts.edu.au/~rheise/sarcastic.cgi`) you'll see it also fails on the your computer.

Comment: Okay if I try to put (http://www.ryanheise.com/sarcastic.cgi) instead it shows (<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

Comment: Which is the first line of the HTML returned by this link. As you're only reading one line of your connection. Looks correct. The difference here is that you probably would need here to read the whole HTML and parse the content of it

Comment: If you check the website (ryanheise.com/sarcastic.cgi) it shows only one line so why it isn't showing that line?

Comment: That website returns a HTML code. This code contains, header, meta data, body, scripts (maybe?). And this code is parsed by the browser (chrome, firefox) to show that 1 line of text.

Answer (score 0):

I went to [your joke page](http://ryanheise.com/sarcastic.cgi) and inspecting the source (in Firefox) and I found this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource://content-accessible/plaintext.css" title="Wrap Long Lines">
  </head>
  <body>
   <pre>I'm really good at stuff until people watch me do that stuff.</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

So you could save the whole output as a `String` and then use  this:

```
string.substring(string.indexOf("<pre>"), string.indexOf("</pre>");
string.substring(4);
```

Basically you are downloading only the first line of the page which would be the content declaration.

Instead you need to download the sixth line and remove the `pre` tags.

Good Luck!